# How to use ISynchronizeInvoke to get data from clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I was trying to use `Clipboard.GetText` with STA thread to get data from clipboard but I have to modify and use `ISynchronizeInvoke` to get data from clipboard any idea how can I use it?

Comment: What are you actually asking? What SATA thread are you talking about? Web applications have no desktop, much less a clipboard. They definitely don't share any clipboard with client applications. `ISynchronizeInvoke` has nothing to do with either. You don't need `ISynchronizeInvoke` for asynchronous operations for the last 11 years, that's what `async/await` are for

Comment: I am using WPF. Talking about STA thread

Comment: You still haven't asked a question. You don't need `Invoke` or `ISynchronizeInvoke` to do something in the UI thread after a background operation, you need `await`. Unless you copied some pre-2012 snippet that uses raw threads or `BeginInvoke` to work in the background

Comment: I don't have any UI operations to do but without await will clipboard operations work ? As per my knowledge without thread we can't access clipboard. Can you also propose some code solution as per your suggestion

Comment: For what problem? All processes have at least one thread so what does `without thread` mean? Are you trying to run some code in the background? Use the Clipboard as a communication mechanism? Post your code

Comment: Are you trying to intercept a user's clipboard actions? Is that why you want to run `Clipboard.GetText` outside the UI thread? Both WPF and Windows Forms offer clipboard events when the user intentionally pastes data into your application

Comment: Maybe you have good reasons which you've not described for using what look like outdated techniques for accessing the clipboard, but if not, maybe you should look for more current WPF clipboard examples. Microsoft has 2 here: https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/main/Clipboard

Answer (score -2):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{    
    string clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText();
});
```

This will work :-)

I have this in my view model base class

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes the specified action on the UI thread.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="action">The action.</param>
protected void Invoke(Action action)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
}

/// <summary>
/// Invokes it if needed on the main thread else uses the current thread
/// </summary>
/// <param name="action"></param>
protected void InvokeIfRequired(Action action)
{
    if (InvokeRequired())
        Invoke(action);
    else
        action.Invoke();
}

/// <summary>
/// Used to test if the action is on a background thread
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
protected bool InvokeRequired() => System.Windows.Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Thread is not null && Thread.CurrentThread != System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread;
```

I find it simple to use, especially with all the async tasks and the await's

This way I do not have to keep track

Comment: Or not - we don't know what the actual question is and using `Invoke` is obsolete since 2012. You can use `await Task.Run(()=>....)` to do anything you want in the background and get back to the UI thread automatically

Comment: I didn't downvote before but I did now. Reimplementing `Control.InvokeRequired` helps nowhere except *creating* serious bugs. If you have to write `.Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Thread` the application code probably run into the obvious bugs of this approach and tried to cover them up

Comment: I'd downvote multiple times if I could because the *ViewModel* is *NOT* supposed to modify the UI at all. It contains data and commands that have no direct reference to the View/WPF screen/window/page/component. WPF uses data binding to render components in thew View using the data in VM properties or sets them after the user modifies the UI. Data binding already has async support. This looks like an attempt to turn WPF into Windows Forms

Comment: Using `System.Windows.Application` in a view model is generally a bad idea. A view model must not have any knowledge of the specifics of a view application, e.g. whether there is a Dispatcher or not.